# Angular JS search filter not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, filter

I am using cordova ionic and building an app with angular js.
I am trying to make a search filter for "apps".An "app" is an object that has an id , a name and so on.
The problem is that the filter seems to be filtering but not the correctly.
it is always returning the same two "apps" even if the text in the search line does not match.I am filtering the "apps" via name. the name is a string - I checked it and the type of "name" that the filter is receiving is in fact string.and I even tried custom filters.The result is still the same.

I assume that the problem is that "app" is an object but after trying many suggestions for dealing with it from various forums (including this one) , it still does not work.

this is the search line code :

```
 <input ng-model="apps[$index].name" type="search" placeholder="Search" class="searchInput">
```

and this is the ng-repeat code where the filter is:

```
 <div ng-repeat="app in apps | filter:apps[$index]" ng-if="$index % per_row == 0" class="row">
```

I also tried :

- putting "name" in both ng-model and filter.
- putting apps[$index].name in both ng-model and filter

And countless other variations.
What can be done to make this work?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try  `<input ng-model="search.name" type="search" placeholder="Search" class="searchInput">` and `<div ng-repeat="app in apps | filter:search" ng-if="$index % per_row == 0" class="row">`

Comment: tried it, didn't work:(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
 <input ng-model="data.appFilter" type="search" placeholder="Search" class="searchInput">
 <div ng-repeat="app in apps | filter:{name: data.appFilter}" ng-if="$index % per_row == 0" class="row">
```

Comment: Just to make sure.. Have you been using console to check all the variables needed? Have you checked if data.appFilter is actually changing in the controller etc?

Comment: Hi, the filter is changing. I checked via alerts and different outputs that the filter is the custom filter.thanks.

Comment: did you figure it out okay?

Comment: I couldn't make it work :(  . I even switched to atom (instead of notepad++) and downloaded linter packages (that show errors in the code) but there are no errors. I'm not sure how well those packages work but... it could be that something is wrong with the logic. I just don't know what.Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Not sure what that per_row var is doing there, and if you look at the element panel in chrome:inspect, you'll probably find something about what's going on.